# Variable Scope in Classes

Tags: javascript, class, variables, scope

I have this code:

```
class Cube {
  constructor(x, y, z, w, h, d, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.d = d;
    this.color = color;
    let cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(w, h, d), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: color}));
  }
  add() {
    scene.add(cube);
  }
  static render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
}
```

I am trying to make a Three.js thing, but that's not the point, so put the render() method aside, because that's not what I'm focusing on.

I have the `cube` variable in the `constructor()`, but I want to be able to access the `cube` variable in `add()`, but because of scope, it raises an error. Is there a way to make it able to be used throughout the whole class without having to put the variable declaration outside of the class `Cube`? Sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: `this.cube = new Three.Mesh(...);`

Answer (score 2):

Make it an instance property, like all the other properties. In the constructor:

```
this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(w, h, d), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: color}));
```

Then reference:

```
scene.add(this.cube);
```